# Failed to print data of a linked-list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm learning about linked list than I wrote a code where I expected to see data1 and data2 displayed on the console window. However, only data1 showed up and I couldn't figure out why.

I wonder if I wrote the member function `print()` wrongly.
Thanks.

Define class `node` as below

```
class node {
    public:
        node(T _data, node* _link) : data(_data), link(_link) {}

        T getdata() { return data; }
        node* getlink() { return link; }
        void setdata(T data) { this->data = data; }
        void setlink(node* link) { this->link = link; }
        void print() {
             while (!isEnd()) {
                    std::cout << data << endl;
                    link = link->link;//go to the next node
            }
        }
        bool isEnd() {
             if (link == NULL)
                 return true;
             return false;
        }

    private:
        T data;
        node* link;
    };
```

Then I implemented the main function as below.

```
//get data1 and data2
    node<int>* Head = new node<int>(data2, NULL);
    Head = new node<int>(data1, Head);

    Head->print();
```

Comment: What is `->link->link` in `print()`? Does this code even compile? Please make a [mre]

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Thanks @cigien for telling me of the mistake.
I've modified my code to a reproducible one.

Comment: Think about what `link = link->link` is really doing. Try to explain it to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Or just use a pencil and some paper to draw the nodes as squares and links as arrows. Erase and redraw arrows as needed when performing operations.

Comment: `print` doesn't print the last node, the one for which `isEnd()` returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print should not be a member function. Instead write a global function like this (I've renamed the function `print_list`).

```
    void print_list(node* n){
        while (!n->isEnd()){
            std::cout << n->getdata() << endl;
            n = n->getlink(); //go to the next node
        }
    }
```

Use it like this

```
    print_list(Head);
```

The node member functions should be things that are about a single node. Printing a list is something that is about a whole list. If you have a list class then it would make sense to make `print` a member of your list class. But since you don't have a list class you should make `print_list` a global function that is not a member of any class.